# Is it possbile to create custom library with namespace

Tags: joomla-3.x, libraries

It is possible to create library package with namespace as below?

```
namespace Main{
  class PrefixFolderLib1{
    //functions
  }
}
```

Not sure how the JLoader will understand the namespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. For example, create `mylib` folder in `/library`, and a file `Myclass.php` with the following content:

```
namespace mylib;

class Myclass
{
}
```

You can register your namespace with

`JLoader::registerNamespace('mylib', JPATH_ROOT . '/libraries');`

And access your class with `\mylib\Myclass`. Personally, I create a system plugin to do it automatically:

```
public function onAfterInitialise()
{  
   JLoader::registerNamespace('mylib', JPATH_ROOT . '/libraries');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I too initialize using system plugin only. In case if I use multiple namespaces then should I register all the name spaces `onAfterInitialise`?

Comment: Yup, you can do it in the same method